# Do OBIEE support PostgreSQL database as a data source?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-connection, business-intelligence, obiee

Have to connect PostgreSQL database from OBIEE? Is it possible to connect and how to do it?

Does OBIEE have native drivers to connect PostgreSQL Database?

Answer (score 1):

You need a PostgreSQL ODBC driver: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/postgresql-jdbc-obiee.rst